# Faster way to decrease the size of this very large CSV file?

Tags: python, performance, csv

I have a very large CSV file of ~1GB that I've acquired with a third-party software that records voltage signals from an apparatus at a sampling rate of 10.000Hz (I'm ommitting details about the software and apparatus to keep this questions succint).

The specific file that I'm working with is the accumulation of ~13 minutes of data (~7.8 million rows). I'm only interested on the data between times 6:00 to time 13:00 of the file.

I want to analyze and plot the data, but this has revealed to be a very difficult task because of the size of the file. In an attempt to make the task easier, I want to take the data from the file and avarage every two frames. If my reasoning is correct, this is almost the equivalent of decreasing the sampling rate to 5KHz, while maintaining a little bit of the information.

I wrote a very simple code with a linear time complexity, and it is taking ages to run...

Since I might have to do this several time in the future, is there a more efficient way of dealing with the data?

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

csv_filename = 'my_path'
header = ['title1', 'title2']

# Skip the first 3,600,001 rows to start analyzing the data at 6 minutes. 

reader = pd.read_csv(csv_filename, header=None, skiprows=3600001, chunksize = 2, names=header)

with open('compressed.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    compressed_header = ["time[s]", "Displacement[um]"]
    writer.writerow(compressed_header)

    time = 0
    for chunk in reader:
        mean = chunk["title2"].mean()
        writer.writerow([time, mean])
        time += 1
```

Comment: Is each row considered 1 frame?

Comment: @JesseSealand, yes, each row is what I'm calling a frame.

Comment: What if you read the `df` at once and then do `df = ((df[::2] + df[1::2].values) / 2).reset_index(drop=True)`. Then save the dataframe to .csv file `df.to_csv("compressed.csv", index_label="time[s]")`

Comment: @AndrejKesely, the file is too large, and pandas cannot read it all into a single df (I get memory errors when I try this). However, I could try what you're proposing with larger chunks! Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @MatheusSchultz Yes, try larger chunks then (to make better use of vectorisation). But ~1GB csv file should fit into memory as pandas dataframe easily...

Comment: Try 50k or 100k records per batch, shouldn't be any problems whatsoever.

Comment: @AndrejKesely it's hard to say without knowing the actual data. For example, for the seconds column, `1` second takes 1 byte in a csv, but 8 bytes in a pd.DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

#### Data format

You want to analyse it, so you do not need to save it back to `csv`. Use some other format that will be faster to save and load afterwards:

- **.npy** (using `numpy.save`) - recommended. Choose data format, smallest possible (float32, int16, int8?) - choice is up to you
- **.wav** (using `scipy.io.wavfile.write`)
- **.pickle** (using `pickle.dump`), easiest to work with, not recommended only because pickle files are dangereous to open.

If you really need .csv, use what Andrej suggested in the comment,  calculate mean on the dataset and save it using `DataFrame.to_csv`.

#### Disregard time column

Also, I am pretty sure you can skip time column, if sampling is uniform, you can forget about it and save lots of space.

If you really need you could save additional info consisting just of two values: sampling frequency and start time.

#### Resampling

Do not resample data before you analyse it or you have full knowledge about what frequency range it contains.

Use Fourier transform (`np.fft.fft`) and plot it first, then decide what resampling can you apply.